# Reading values from Wiznet w5500 chip over SPI

Tags: ethernet, spi

I am trying to get the MAC address that is stored on the Wiznet w5500 chip.

On [page 29 - click here](http://wizwiki.net/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=products:w5500:w5500_ds_v107e_160224.pdf), it has the address of the values. It state that "This block can be selected by the BSB[4:0] value of SPI Frame". Then it lists the addresses of the MAC block from 0x001E to 0x0023.

How do I read these blocks using the SPI library? What does the BSB[4:0] mean?

EDIT 1: I am looking through the Wiznet Arduino library and it looks like there is a way to access the mac address through

Comment: Page 29 of what? Could you share this document with us please?

Comment: @MarkSmith thanks for pointing that out. I added the link.

Comment: The initial value is 00.00.00.00. The library/sketch sets the MAC address.

Comment: @MikaelPatel so there is no way to read the MAC into the software? I would have to use a separate MAC as a unique identifier?

Comment: You can read the SHAR register into the software but the initial value is not unique. Some Ethernet Shields have a sticker with an allocated MAC address to use. See http://wizwiki.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=501 and http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8719/didnt-have-mac-address-on-wiznet-based-ethernet-shield-cloned

Comment: @MikaelPatel ok. I thought the chip had a dedicated MAC burned into it. I guess I will just use an extra component with a MAC burned in the EEPROM.